# Raspberry Pi 3b Plus USB-Ethernet lan78xx_eth address not set by u-boot

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B Plus which I want to integrate with U-boot (v2023.10) .

I am using `rpi_3_32b_defconfig` to generate `u-boot.bin`. But while booting I am getting below error

```
Loading Environment from FAT... Unable to read "uboot.env" from mmc0:1...
In:    serial,usbkbd
Out:   serial,vidconsole
Err:   serial,vidconsole
Net:   No ethernet found.
starting USB...
Bus usb@7e980000: USB DWC2
scanning bus usb@7e980000 for devices...
Error: lan78xx_eth address not set.
3 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
```

In the `bdinfo`, "current eth" is not set

```
U-Boot> bdinfo
boot_params = 0x00000100
DRAM bank   = 0x00000000
-> start    = 0x00000000
-> size     = 0x3b400000
flashstart  = 0x00000000
flashsize   = 0x00000000
flashoffset = 0x00000000
baudrate    = 115200 bps
relocaddr   = 0x3b360000
reloc off   = 0x3b358000
Build       = 32-bit
current eth = unknown
eth-1addr   = (not set)
IP addr     = <NULL>
```

I also enabled `LAN75xx` in `menuconfig` and re-compiled u-boot. But still the same error.

However on Raspberry Pi 3B, I don't see this error and "current eth" is set to "smsc95xx_eth" and `ethaddr` is also available.

Can anyone please let me know the issue with Raspberry Pi 3b plus?

Thanks in advance.